ClassifierChain ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'eval'
I'm attempting to use ClassifierChain on CatBoostClassifier. See the code below.
Xs consist of numerical/categorical features
Y is a 2d boolean matrix.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/qt/pddm3t3951g42p57pf8yms780000gn/T/ipykernel_81478/3196626518.py in ?()
     11 clf = CatBoostClassifier(reg_lambda=0.001,
---> 12                         iterations=450,
     13                         depth=5,
     14                         learning_rate=0.01,
     15                         loss_function='MultiLogloss',

~/miniforge3/envs/m_arch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1148                 skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149                     prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150                 )
   1151             ):
-> 1152                 return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

~/miniforge3/envs/m_arch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/multioutput.py in ?(self, X, Y, **fit_params)
    929                 "fit_params is only supported if enable_metadata_routing=True. "
    930                 "See the User Guide for more information."
    931             )
    932 
--> 933         super().fit(X, Y, **fit_params)
    934         self.classes_ = [
    935             estimator.classes_ for chain_idx, estimator in enumerate(self.estimators_)
    936         ]
...
   2151         if (
   2152             astype_is_view(values.dtype, arr.dtype)
   2153             and using_copy_on_write()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'eval'

Below is the code I attempted.
cat_feature_idx/feature_idx is for specifying the indices in the catboostclassifier argument. there are only 5 numerical features. after imputation, the df idx order is now become [numerial features + categorical features] instead of the original order of the columns from the X, hence the "feature_idx[-cat_feature_idx:]" in the argument.
I've tested the model without the ClassifierChain, but prompted error when including it.
2 possible reason I'm suspecting the reason error occur:

ClassifierChain is including the predictions of models that are earlier in the chain, thus making the X larger, however the CatBoostClassifier could not identify whether the new "features" is category or numeric (or perhaps the indices of the columns are shuffle now), hence the error.

in one of my columns from the new_X_train, the value 'eval' cause the error.
suspecting the phrase 'eval' prompt the error or I have mess up the order in my transfored X_train


the list is the cat_features indices to be specify in the CatboostClassifier feature_idx[-cat_feature_idx:]
I'm not sure if this theory is correct nor know the way to investigate more into this.
Below is the code.
hamming_scorer = make_scorer(hamming_loss, greater_is_better=False)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', IterativeImputer(random_state=42), numerical_features),
        ('cat', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'), categorical_features)
    ])

cat_feature_idx = X.shape[1] - len(numerical_features) 
feature_idx = np.arange(X.shape[1])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', IterativeImputer(random_state=42), numerical_features),
        ('cat', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'), categorical_features)
    ])
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor)])
new_X_train = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)


clf = CatBoostClassifier(reg_lambda=0.001,
                        iterations=450,
                        depth=5,
                        learning_rate=0.01,
                        loss_function='MultiLogloss', 
                        eval_metric='HammingLoss', 
                        cat_features=feature_idx[-cat_feature_idx:], 
                        verbose=0,
                        random_seed=42)
chains = [ClassifierChain(clf, order="random", random_state=i) for i in range(10)]
for chain in chains:
    chain.fit(X_train, y_train)

